# When to use multiple CPP files (Good Coding Practice)

Tags: c++, coding-style

When writing a C++ program what is considered to be good practice in regards to using multiple cpp files?

IE If you are writing a rather large (lines of code based) object it would generally be easier for comprehension purposes to divide the program in multiple sections.

Lets say you have a thousand lines of just constructors and then a 1000 lines of foo and another of bar. Generally it would be easier for one to read it if they understood they are just viewing all the variations of foo, bar, constructors or any other methods.

What do you consider to be "good practices?" Do you base it on lines of code? 
Do you do these partitions even in smaller programs (sub 1000 lines total).

I understand this is subjective but what are the rules of the thumbs for dividing your program/object/etc amongst multiple cpp files?

Comment: Think *Encapsulaton*.  Keep amount of lines small; large files breed defects.  I recommend refactoring by theme.

Comment: Large numbers of files also breed defects. In C++ you should aim for one class = one file.

Comment: It's something you MUST know. And I don't mean that you MUST already know, but in a project you can see that there will be a logical distribution that makes sense. I tend to do this very well without much effort because I am from a scientific background and it is natural to me to think in terms of "*systems*", thus defining a system with total clarity allows me to choose how many modules and files and "*objects*" will a program have. NOTE: I used object for the lack of a more *generic* term, or at least for my ignorance of such term.

Comment: Also, I voted to close as opinion based but I don't think it's entirely opinion based, there must be an optimal distribution. It surely will depend on the project, but perhaps the method for the determination of such distribution can be general and applicable in most situations. I still voted, because this question does not qualify for stack overflow anyway, but it's a good question so you should ask somewhere else. Also, as many others have mentioned in c++ 1 file 1 class helps a lot, I don't think it's accidentally mandatory in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Try to limit yourself to one class per file.  If that class is extremely long you could try to break it into multiple files, but this may only complicate things.  Be sure to leave enough blank lines to make the code more readable and to leave enough comments so that you and others can figure out what the code does in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Most people typically break up their files by a loosly defined category that makes sense to the programmers on the project.

For example, if you are coding a calculator, you might have a main cpp for input, then a cpp for error handling, another cpp for binary operators, another for unary, ... or you can split it up by having a main cpp for input, output, and error handling, and a cpp for all possible math functions. It really depends on how *structured* you want to be and how you define a category or section.

Here is a good quote from [this website](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/18-programs-with-multiple-files/):

> As programs get larger, it is not uncommon to split them into multiple files for organizational or reusability purposes. One advantage of working with an IDE is they make working with multiple files much easier. You already know how to create and compile single-file projects. Adding new files to existing projects is very easy.